# From grep Perl style regex syntax to actual Perl regex pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I'm unable to convert Perl regex used in grep to perl syntax

```
#/bin/bash
string="Last logical block address=936640511 (0x37d3ffff), Number of blocks=936640512"
echo $string | grep -Po '(?<=blocks=)[^$]*'
```

with perl, I'm unable to succeed

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string="Last logical block address=936640511 (0x37d3ffff), Number of blocks=936640512";
my ($blocks) = $string =~ m/(?<=blocks=)[^$]*/;
print $blocks;
```

Please advice if I'm using the correct regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The match operator in list context returns the captured texts if there are any, so all you need to do is add a capture (parens) around the bit you want returned.

```
my ($blocks) = $string =~ /(?<=blocks=)([^$]*)/;
print "$blocks\n";
```

The lookbehind is just slowing you down.

```
my ($blocks) = $string =~ /blocks=([^$]*)/;
print "$blocks\n";
```

We should check if the match actually succeeded.

```
if ( my ($blocks) = $string =~ /blocks=([^$]+)/ ) {
    print "$blocks\n";
}
```

But I'm confused as to why you're matching characters other than the dollar sign. You probably meant to match characters other than the newline.

```
if ( my ($blocks) = $string =~ /blocks=([^\n]+)/ ) {
    print "$blocks\n";
}
```

Given that you aren't using `/s`, that can also be written

```
if ( my ($blocks) = $string =~ /blocks=(.+)/ ) {
    print "$blocks\n";
}
```

Personally, I'd use

```
if ( my ($blocks) = $string =~ /blocks=(\S+)/ ) {
    print "$blocks\n";
}
```

To get all matches, it's just a question of using `/g`.

```
for my $blocks ( $string =~ /blocks=(\S+)/g ) {
    print "$blocks\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks ikegami. But in truth both answers are failing as my `$string` is a multiline output - `Read Capacity results:
   Last logical block address=936640511 (0x37d3ffff), Number of blocks=936640512
   Logical block length=512 bytes
Hence:
   Device size: 479559942144 bytes, 457344 MiB, 479.56 GB`

Comment: Thanks ikegami!! I have obtained the required output.

Answer (score 1):

The `[^$]` pattern matches "anything except a literal `$`", not end-of-string as you intended.

Try this instead:

```
if ($str =~ m/(?<=blocks=)(.*)$/)
{
    my $blocks = $1;
    print $blocks;
}
```

You can also print `$&` which is a special variable (`man perlvar`) corresponding to the last matched string. Then you don't need to use the `()` capture or `$1`.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the meaning of `=~`, but I tried the above snippet and I see only a blank. Does this mean match was failure?

Comment: ug, don't use `$&`. It slows down every regex match without captures in your program.

Comment: @dvnrrs, while you are right about the 2nd point (regex) your first point is wrong. OP is doing the match in list context and hence $blocks would contain the matched value. Check the section under 'Matching in list context' in the perldoc perlop page.

Comment: @sateesh Thanks; removed that from the answer. @ikegami Regarding `$1` vs. `$&` I'll leave it as-is since I present both options without taking a stance on which is better.

Comment: Mentioning it at all is taking a stance that it's acceptable, but you should never use `$&`.

Comment: @ikegami "Mentioning it at all is taking a stance that it's acceptable." I respectfully disagree. Like it or not, it's a feature of the language.

Comment: If you disagree, then what are you trying to communicate by mentioning it?